# Váriável $_POST tem limite de tamanho?

Tags: php

Estou trabalhando com a variável `$_POST` em uma determinada parte do sistema que estou desenvolvendo, só que quando eu faço um `submit` de um formulário do tipo POST nem todas as informações são passadas para esta variável `$_POST`.

Existe algum limite tamanho para variáveis do tipo `$_POST`, e se há, como eu poderia contornar isto?

Comment: Poste o codigo cliente que esta efetuando a requisiçao POST.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, o `$_POST` possui um limite maximo definido pela configuraçao `post_max_size` do PHP, porem esse valor geralmente é suficiente para informaçoes textuais.

Seria interessante voce conferir se voce nao possui atributos `name` repetidos no formulario que esta enviado, pois isso pode fazer com que as informacoes de um campo substituam a de outro.

**EDIT:** Baseado em seu comentario informando que esta tentando enviar um array, voce pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<input name="nota[0]">
<input name="nota[1]">
<input name="nota[2]">
<input name="nota[3]">
```

Voce pode acessar as notas no array usando `$_POST['nota']`.

Comment: Acontece que as names são três: nota_1, nota_2 e nota_final, pois se trata de um boletim, esses nomes são seguidos de [] para que sejam enviados arrays com informações, o que acontece é que este array não envia todos os dados que estão no formulário.

Comment: @Kaluã Veja a minha resposta editada e veja se te ajuda.

Comment: Agora imagina ai um array contendo uma boa parte dos dados do formulário em questão, o problema é que nem todos os dados estão sendo armazenados dentro desta array, se formos seguir o vc falow no inicio, somenete uma informação para cada name estariam lá, só que a realidade é que há dados na array só que também há dados que não estão sendo inseridos nesta array.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é uma limitação de servidor, se for a `php.ini` e pesquisar por `post_max_size` pode verificar qual o tamanho limite que tem para passar dados através de `POST`.

Ou mudar através de `.htaccess` para o valor que necessite:

```
#definir tamanho máximo de POST
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

Answer (score 1):

O POST pode ser bloqueado por duas variaveis de configuração.

A primeira já mencionada nas outras respostas é o `post_max_size`, que controla a quantidade limite em MB que pode ser recebida via POST.

A segunda variavel é o `max_input_vars` que foi introduzida no php 5.3.9 para evitar ataques do tipo HashDOS. Esta variavel controla a quantidade de campos que pode ser enviada por POST/GET e normalmente é setada com um limite de 1000 campos.

Recomendo a tomar bastante cuidado quando for alterar qualquer uma dessas variaveis, visto que ela já possuem valores baixos para evitar problemas de `DOS` (Denial Of Service)

Para o caso de estar mechendo com arquivos é interessante notar que existe uma diretiva que controla isto tambem: `upload_max_filesize` - Controla quantos MB podem ser enviados em Uploads.