# max_input_vars tem algum limite de valor?

Tags: php

A variavel de configuração max_input_vars tem algum valor limite? Eu estou setando o valor dessa variavel para 9999999 mas mesmo assim o PHP está reclamando que o valor sendo enviado é maior do que 20000, 20000 seria o valor limite para se colocar nessa variavel?

Comment: [Váriável $_POST tem limite de tamanho?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40768/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O **max_input_vars** é relativo a quantidade de variaveis.

Talvez seu problema seja com o tamanho (em bytes) do conteudo enviado. Existem outras configs relacionadas a isso, como o **post_max_size**

Se a reclamação é do valor enviado, então é o tamanho (em bytes) dele e não a quantidade de variáveis.

Comment: Eu modifiquei o post_max_size, o erro demorou mais pra acontecer mas aconteceu. Acho que estou tentando enviar muitos dados de uma vez só

Comment: talvez seja o caso de rever a lógica...se quiser compartilhar o que exatamente está fazendo, talvez eu consiga te ajudar